# Can I use aws api gateway to get rid of a web server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I would like to to something like this:

Every petition to http://example.com/front1/ get the content from a s3 bucket.

Every petition to http://example.com/front2/ get the content from another s3 bucket.

Every petition to http://example.com/microservice1/ get the content from a microservice.

Every petition to http://example.com/microservice2/ get the content from another microservice.

The rest of petitions to http://example.com/ get the content from another s3 bucket.

It works with apache having a virtualhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/tmp"

  <Directory "/tmp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/example.com_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/example.com_access.log" "forwarded" 

  ## Proxy rules
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost Off

  ProxyPass /front1/ http://front1.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/
  ProxyPassReverse /front1/ http://front1.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

  ProxyPass /front2/ http://front2.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/
  ProxyPassReverse /front2/ http://front2.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

  ProxyPass /microservice1/ http://my-alb.com/microservice1/
  ProxyPassReverse /microservice1/ http://my-alb.com/microservice1/

  ProxyPass /microservice2/ http://my-alb.com/microservice2/
  ProxyPassReverse /microservice2/ http://my-alb.com/microservice2/

  ProxyPass / http://front-default.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://front-default.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But I'm trying not to have an apache and I was trying to do it with aws api gateway.

The problems is that I'm not able to serve correctly for example the images. It seems that api gateway is prepared for calls retrieving json.

Im I right?

Is there any other solutions to not have a web server?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a mixture of Route53 and an ALB.

Set up a Route53 Alias record under example.com for each of the S3 buckets, and configure these buckets as static S3 websites.

Then set up Route53 Alias records to a path-based ALB, and add two Listeners to this ALB - one routing to the TargetGroup for microservice1 on /microservice1/* and the other routing to Microservice 2 on the path /microservice2/*

This is fairly simple and requires no web server to mediate.

Comment: Hi @mcfinnigan,  Thanks for your answer but I think it does not resolve the question. I want all urls for users be like example.com/xxxxx